# can we write render inside a function component in react?

Tags: reactjs, components

```
render(){
        return (<div>
            <form>
          
            <input type='textarea' placeholder='enter city'/>
            <br/>
            <div className='temp'>
            <input className='Fahren' type='radio'/>
            <label for='temp'>Fahrenheit</label>
            <input className='Celc' type='radio'/>
            <label for='temp'>Celcuis</label>
            </div>
            <br></br>
           <Search/>
            <button type='submit'>Get Forecast</button>
            </form>
    
            </div>);
}
};

    export default App;
```

the above code was working fine when I wrote return( with entire code ) but when I tried using render it's throwing an error "syntax error: /Users/Deeksha/Documents/reactandnodejs/weather-app/src/Components/App.js: Missing semicolon (7:8)"

Comment: you don't need a render function inside a function component. just return your jsx directly.

Comment: `render` is needed only for the class component.

Comment: Its all in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your function supposed to be called App with a proper function construct?

```
function App (){
        return (<div>
            <form>
          
            <input type='textarea' placeholder='enter city'/>
            <br/>
            <div className='temp'>
            <input className='Fahren' type='radio'/>
            <label for='temp'>Fahrenheit</label>
            <input className='Celc' type='radio'/>
            <label for='temp'>Celcuis</label>
            </div>
            <br></br>
           <Search/>
            <button type='submit'>Get Forecast</button>
            </form>
    
            </div>);
}

export default App;
```

or

```
const App = props => (
   <div>
            <form>
          
            <input type='textarea' placeholder='enter city'/>
            <br/>
            <div className='temp'>
            <input className='Fahren' type='radio'/>
            <label for='temp'>Fahrenheit</label>
            <input className='Celc' type='radio'/>
            <label for='temp'>Celcuis</label>
            </div>
            <br></br>
           <Search/>
            <button type='submit'>Get Forecast</button>
            </form>
    
       </div>);

    export default App;
```

Looks to me like a syntax error